# print only specific Values in Array with pairs

Tags: python, arrays, plot, zip

I have an array in the form of

```
array1= [(radius1, mass1), (radius2, mass2), .... ]
```

And I have a second array in the form of

```
array2=[density1, density2,...]
```

Both arrays have the same number of elements (716).
What I want to do is to plot masses from my array1 against the densities of array2. Something like

```
plt.plot(array1[1], array2)
```

I do know that array1[1] gives me the first pair of my array (radius1, mass1), but I don't know how else I can describe what type of solution I am looking for.

Two ideas are:
- unzip my array1 so that I have two lists (one for all radii, and one for all masses)
- instead of an array I could use a matrix, so that I can call the specific column, where the masses are.

However I do not know how to do those things. And I'd rather not separate my pairs, since I will need to sort my datapairs according to radius, but always will plot the mass.

I hope that I explained everything you need to know. If not I will of course add missing information here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `masses =[a[1] for a in array1]` will give you the masses.

Comment: thanks, and sorry for the duplicate - I have not found this question when I was looking for it. I even scrolled through those suggestions that came up after typing the name of my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get the second number (at index `1`) of each tuple:

```
plt.plot([t[1] for t in array1], array2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! :)